# Batch file behaves differently from the Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a very simple batch file that I have written to visit a URL wait 2 minutes for it to load then close the browser:

```
start iexplore.exe http://myURL
timeout /t 120
taskkill /im iexplore.exe /f
```

The reason why I've created this is to wake up some services in the morning because the first person to log in always sees errors. Double clicking on the .bat file works perfectly, but when I run it as a scheduled task it does not open the web browser. I know that the task is running properly beyond that because if I open a Web browser in the meantime it will close 2 minutes after I started the task.

Could anyone tell me why the browser is not opening from the scheduled task and what I need to change?

Comment: Are there any error logs in the task scheduler?  What was the exit code for the last time it was run?  My initial guess is that you'll need to specify the "start in..." path.

Comment: @Sculper No errors - it says it ran sucessfully. I'm not sure where to find an exit code - I'm reading Run result (Sucess) Run Start and Run End in the task scheduler history.

Would that be to start in the directory where the iexplore.exe is stored?

Comment: You would start in the directory in which the batch file is located, and call the it by name.  So if your .bat file is located `C:\some directory\some.bat`, you would start in  `C:\some directory\ ` and call `some.bat`.  That said, since it completed successfully I doubt that's the issue.  Is the task being run with highest privileges?

Comment: @Sculper It wasn't but it is now and doesn't seem to make any difference. I've also added the start in with the same result.

Comment: It actually seems to be opening it now, according to the logs of the url. I dont think it was to start with though so it must have been one of those changes. It still wont show a web browser but for my purposes it now works. Thanks for your help @Sculper

Comment: Right, I've identified the change I made that fixed it. Initially I did not have the 'iexplore.exe'. The bat file worked when double clicked on, but not from the scheduler, then when I added that the bat file will access the URL from both double clicking and the scheduler but will only display the page from double clicking. - hope that clears it up to anyone with the same problem.